# F string inside For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I dont understand why this doesn't work. I am trying to do a For Loop to save my error measures:

```
error = []
naive_list = list(['24', '168', 'standard', 'custom'])
for i in naive_list:
    for j in range(1,5):
        rmse = mean_squared_error(df_test["f'Price_REG{j}'"], f'df_test_{i}'["f'Price_REG{j}'"], squared=False)
        mae = mae(df_test["f'Price_REG{j}'"], f'df_test_{i}'["f'Price_REG{j}'"])
        error.append(rmse)
        error.append(mae)
```

The idea is to save all of these 16 measures so I can reach them later, be it in separate variables, in a dict, or a list.

First I tried to use f'string on the variable name too `f'rmse_{i}_{j} = mean_squared_error(df_test["f'Price_REG{j}'"], f'df_test_{i}'["f'Price_REG{j}'"], squared=False)` but apparently this is not possible. So instead I tried to put them all in one list, like above. But I am getting a error on the f'string `KeyError: "f'Price_REG{j}'"`.

Comment: Why to you include your "f-strings" inside a string? So it will never be evaluated. If you want a f-string, do it a `df_test[f'Price_REG{j}']`, etc.

Comment: yes, the `f` in f-strings goes before the first quote, not inside the quotes.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I didn't realize it wouldn't be evaluated. The reason is that `df_test[Price_REG1]` doesn't work, since I need the column the be within quotation insde the brackets, like `df_test['Price_REG1']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `df_test["f'Price_REG{j}'"]` literally means the string `df_test["f'Price_REG{j}'"]`. It will not be evaluated further. It's a string-literal.

Instead `df_test[f'Price_REG{j}']` WOULD be evaluated and would return whatever is in `Price_REG{j}` and then fetch the column of the same name from the df.

That being said, because that f-string contains only a variable, it's functionally equivalent to just `df_test[Price_REG{j}]`.

You have painted yourself into a corner over-engineering. None of the f-strings and string-literals with f-strings inside them are needed here. Just the variable themselves, with no quotes around them.

Instead:

```
error = []
naive_list = list(['24', '168', 'standard', 'custom'])
for i in naive_list:
    for j in range(1,5):
        rmse = mean_squared_error(df_test[Price_REG{j}], df_test_{i}[Price_REG{j}], squared=False)
        mae = mae(df_test[Price_REG{j}], df_test_{i}[Price_REG{j}])
        error.append(rmse)
        error.append(mae)
```

What I'm not sure about though is whatever `df_test_` is or what `df_test_{i}` is meant to do. Nor am I fully understanding the curly braces of `Price_REG{j}` (should those be square brackets? What is `Price_REG`?). But at any rate, at least you are free of your painted corner and continue hammering out whatever other kinks may pop up in this code.

Comment: I´ve been struggling with these things, knowing when to use f'strings or not. I thought curly braces was the only way to put these different iterations inside a string. Would square brackets work too? `Price_REG{j}` is used to compare the error measure for 4 different regions, on at a time. `df_test` is just the prices that I am comparing my predicted prices to, ´df_test_{i}` is the predicted prices, so `df_test_24` is one of the predicted series, which means the first iterations will compare the original prices in region 1, to the `df_test_24` predicted prices in region one.

Comment: your example give me Invalid Syntax. Am I not required to use quotes within the square brackets to refer to the column, like `df['Column1']`

Comment: OH! I see now about the curly braces. You are using f-strings to dynamically refer to variables. I don't know why I didn't wrap my head around that. That's very creative. So... Instead of dynamically referring to variables, use a dictionary instead. `df_dict={"df_test_1":df_test_1, "df_test_2": df_test_2, "df_test_3":df_test3 ...}` and `price_reg_dict={"Price_Reg1": Price_REG1, "Price_REG2":Price_REG2... }`. Then in your code you can do `mae = mae(df_test[price_reg_dict["Price_REG"+j]], df_dict["df_test_" + i][price_reg_dict["Price_REG"+j]])` This gets you our f-string "inception"

Comment: My basic boiler plate here is "Any time you are thinking `Dynamically referring to variables` or `variable variable names` instead think `Dictionaries`". This is the same in nearly every language, even ones that support dynamically referencing variables like php. It's just bad practice when dictionaries are available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Many of my solutions tend to be creative, but maybe not optimal. I will try to get used to using dict when doing this sort of stuff in the future. I found a alternative solution before you answered, I changed the `j` variable to `naive_list = (['df_test_24', 'df_test_168', 'df_test_standard', 'df_test_custom'])` and then `mae = mean_absolute_error(df[column].iloc[s:m], locals()[j][column].iloc[s:m])`. So `locals()[j]` will be `df_test_24` in the first iteration and so forth.